# How to load results of bash command into gcs using Airflow?

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I try to save json that is a result of bash command in the bucket of gcs. Executing the bash command in my local terminal everything works properly and it loads data into gcs. Unfortunately the same bash command doesn't work via Airflow. Airflow marks the task as successfully done but in gcs I can see empty file. I suspect that this happens because of the out of airflow memory but I am not sure. If so someone can explain me how and where the results are stored in airflow ? I see in the [bash operator documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/operators/bash_operator.html) that airflow creates a temporary directory which is cleaned after the execution. Does it mean that the results of bash command also are cleaned afterwards ? Is there any way to save the results in gcs ?

This is my dag:

```
get_data = BashOperator(
    task_id='get_data',
    bash_command='curl -X GET -H 'XXX: xxx' some_url | gsutil cp -L manifest.txt - gs://bucket/folder1/filename.json; rm manifest.txt',
    dag=dag
)
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you're not using the Airflow operator for this particular task, this one https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/gcs_to_gcs.py

Comment: @Ismail I don't use gcs_to_gcs operator because I don't need to move files between buckets but I need to insert there files from other application and with the application I communicate via API

Comment: The problem is already solved. The problem was with bash command itself. It could not interpreted passed headers correctly. 

Just in case:

I observed that using python operator with response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers) worked more stable then using bash operator

Comment: Glad to hear that. I'm going to add the Python tag to this thread. I also would recommend for you to answer the question since you have all the details :)
Let me know whether I can help you further